# What is the best way to store history of data in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

There is an app I'm building using Firebase Realtime Database. Users of this app will be able to create a post and edit it anytime they want. Also, they're allowed to access all versions of the post, but they'll get the latest version by default. I've got this so far:

```
Realtime Database-root
   |
   --- posts
        |
        --- postId
                 |
                 --- versionId
                 |           |
                 |           --- uid
                 |           |
                 |           --- title
                 |           |
                 |           --- date
                 |           
                 --- versionId
                             |
                             --- uid
                             |
                             --- title
                             |
                             --- date
```

However, I'm afraid that this is the best way to go. Could this approach be improved considering cost, scalability, security and performance?

Comment: If post has plain text format you can store only `diff`. Mean GNU diff. And if necessary apply patches to show complete text for user.

Answer (score 0):

Since the RTDB costs $5 per GB stored I would recommend that you use Google Storage as a cheap datastore to store your versions.

What that means is your database should store posts like this:

```
Realtime Database-root
   |
   --- posts
        |
        --- postId
                 |
                 --- uid
                 |
                 --- title
                 |
                 --- date
   --- postsVersions
        |
        --- postId
                 |
                 --- version1Id: true
                 |
                 --- version2Id: true
```

`version1Id` and `version2Id` reference JSON documents stored in Google Storage.

**Workflow**

1. User creates the initial post and the database entry is made.
2. User makes changes and saves them to the RTDB, overwriting the previous version in `/posts`.
3. A Cloud Function that is triggered on the `onUpdate()` event on `/posts/{postId}` takes the previous version and saves it to Google Storage as `https://storage.google.com/<bucket>/<postId>/<version1Id>.json` and saves that versionId to `/postsVersions`.
4. If the user deletes the `version1Id` key from that `/postsVersions`, a Cloud Function monitoring the `onDelete()` event on `/postsVersions/{postId}` should delete that JSON file from Google Storage.
5. Finally if the user would like to load a previous version of a post, they make a simple HTTPS request to retrieve the JSON file from Google Storage and then they update `/posts` with the previous version.

**Security**

You should make sure that your version IDs are unguessable and non-sequential and you can then simply provide blanket access to the bucket using IAM permissions for all authenticated users.  For more granular control where users can't potentially access other users' versioned posts, a non-public bucket and an API endpoint that generates a signedURL would be simple to implement.

Comment: For clarity, the Realtime Database is $5Gb on the paid [Blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) whereas the Free Plan offers 1Gb; 1Gb is a LOT of posts even with older versions stored as well. Also, If you are referring to storing JSON in [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) that could be problematic as that's not generally it's purpose (it can be done though) as it's not queryable/readable as JSON by the RTDB *Cloud Storage is built for app developers who need to store and serve user-generated content, such as photos or videos*. Maybe that's not an issue?

Comment: I like this idea, but I also agree @Jay. Cloud Storage might not be suitable for this case because there is a security problem here even if everything works fine. Cloud storage's security rules are limited to its own purposes. There is no way to check user permissions without having an access to Realtime database.

Comment: @StewieGriffin for a few years I was running an Amazon price tracker using GCS to store and retrieve historical price data in a similar method and never broke out of the free tier.  It's a viable, scalable and cost effective solution that I highly recommend if you're trying to keep costs low.  You can address security issues either by using unguessable version names or even a simple API endpoint that provides a signed URL to the object.

Comment: @Jay **"If you are referring to storing JSON in Cloud Storage that could be problematic as that's not generally it's purpose"**  I'm not sure where you're sourcing that from, I've done something similar on a very busy site and it scales incredibly well. **"it's not queryable/readable as JSON by the RTDB"**  It wouldn't need to be, if the client wants to revert, they download that specific version from GCS and then push the JSON to the RTDB as a normal update.

Comment: I was not stating it couldn't be done, just that the main intention as stated in the official docs is more for blob type data. I am sourcing that from the official documentation [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). I just wanted some clarity about the use case as it cannot be queried. e.g. if you want to query the "archive" for a particular post, that's not possible with this implementation. However, if it's a revert then sure - it would work. Just adding a bit more info to a good answer.